# Zend Framework: Zend_Navigation menu links rendering bug?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

i am having this scenario where when i goto a url like `/posts/add`, my menu items will all render `posts/add`. when i goto `/posts` its all right

my [nav config](http://pastebin.com/RfAfxkwE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring the route for each - `<route>default</route>`.